# Javascript going through a Proxy

Tags: javascript, proxy

I am working on a project right now that requires some javascript for the proper functionality we are looking for.  The problem we are running into is that the clients of this web-based app can only access the site through a proxy server (due to strict policies).  This proxy server is stripping the javascript from the page and we are unable to replicate the exact proxy setting to determine a solution.  Has anyone ran into this problem before and found a solution?

Comment: 1) serverfault. 2) Without knowing which proxy server, I don't see how anyone is likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a fixed set of client machines, and you can go for Firefox only, you might be able to do something using a Firefox extension or a bookmarklet that fetches the Javascript some other way that the proxy doesn't recognize (e.g. as base64 encoded data). It would however certainly require a load of work, and you may have to program the extension yourself... Probably cheaper to buy a new Proxy.

Comment: I have a second very sneaky idea but would have to do some research for it, so I need to know first whether the working environment is in fact fixed, and there is access to the client computers.

Answer (score 0):

Some of our customers had these problems and we told them to access our app via HTTPS and that cleared the issue since most proxy won't filter secured traffic.

Comment: I will have to try that, I was also told be a previous developer that inline scripting with onclick attributes work, so I am going to try that.  If no luck Ill try the https option